# PHP Get POST Value from Ajax to PHP with 2 condition

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Assume I have 2 textbox, that's serial_no10 and serial_no12. That 2 textbox appear not simultaneously depends on case
1 PHP file for checking the SN.
1 DIV status to display the data.

**jQuery Ajax**

```
var serial_no10 = $("#serial_no10").val();
var serial_no12 = $("#serial_no12").val();

$.ajax(
{
    type: "POST",
    url: "chk_dvd_part_no.php",
    data: 'serial_no10='+ serial_no10 +'&serial_no12='+ serial_no12,
    success: function(msg)
    {
         $("#status").ajaxComplete(function(event, request, settings)
         {
         }
    }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="status"></div>
```

PHP File

```
if(!empty($_POST['serial_no12']))
{
     echo "Serial No 12";
}
else if(!empty($_POST['serial_no10']))
{
     echo "Serial No 10";
}
```

Now I'm facing the problem when get POST from textbox serial_no_12, the value is undefined. But if get POST from textbox serial_no_10, I got the value.

Is that something wrong with that PHP code? Or I do something that should not be.

Comment: Can you show your full code or pasre it into JSfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

You have to just empty the variables before filling up. As if value is not reset then last value computed would remain in variavar

```
serial_no10 = $("#serial_no10").val();
var serial_no12 = $("#serial_no12").val();ble
```

change it with

```
var serial_no10='';
var serial_no12='';
serial_no10 = $("#serial_no10").val();
serial_no12 = $("#serial_no12").val();
```

Noww do things it will all good

Comment: if you do not to get undefined then fill the buffer the randowm value at begining var serial_no="148934" and var serial_no12="148934"

Answer (score 0):

Give your form tag an id if it has no anyone. and than do something like this.

```
var form = $("#form_id").serialize();

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "chk_dvd_part_no.php",
    data: form,
    success:function(msg)
    {
         $("#status").ajaxComplete(function(event, request, settings)
         {
              //do your stuff
         });
    }
});
```

and in php file get your post variable by its name, suppose you have 2 inputs name serial_no10 and serial_no12

now do your php code like this.

```
if( isset($_POST['serial_no10']) && $_POST['serial_no10'] != '' ){
    echo 'Serial No 10';
}
if( isset($_POST['serial_no12']) && $_POST['serial_no12'] != '' ){
    echo 'Serial No 12';
}
```